# How do I bind a GridView to a custom object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, gridview

If I have the following ASP.NET code (it's not complete - obviously there's a lot missing, but none of it matters):

```
    <asp:GridView>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    My Label: <asp:Label />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    My Text Box: <asp:TextBox />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And if I have something like this in the CodeBehind:

```
Private MyListOfObjects As List(Of MyObject)

...

Public Class MyObject

    Public MyTextBoxString as String
    Public MyLabelString as String

End Class
```

How can I bind the GridView so that one row is equivalent to one item in my `MyListOfObjects` list, and so that the data will populate and persist across page loads or postbacks? I've never done custom databinding like this before, so a full explanation would be very helpful. All the tutorials I've come across so far only talk about using GridViews directly with Database query results, and that's not what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Check if this helps: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/04/28/binding-list-of-custom-class-to-gridview-or-listview-control.aspx

Comment: see my response to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the datasource of the gridview to your object.

```
MyGridView.DataSource = myList
MyGridView.DataBind()
```

Here's a very similiar post:

[Binding a method that returns List<employee> to a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399793/binding-a-method-that-returns-listemployee-to-a-gridview/3399808#3399808)

Looks like you are using a list in vb.net.  Remember lists can hold integers, strings, dates, objects (these include user defined types (your object)).
So you can bind a gridview to a list object by setting the datasource property to your list.

In the above example, myList, might hold a ton of employee objects, etc.  So assign it to the datasource and `.DataBind()` and voila a gridview with each row containing your object.

Comment: Except I've predefined my columns beforehand, and my list doesn't match up to the columns, so I need to manually specify and map the rows to objects inside my list.

Comment: @SpikeX - You don't need to do anything, whatever columns you've `<TemplateField>` from your grid view will be displayed.  For instance, assume you have a customer object with 3 properties age, name, and birthdate.  If you only want to show name, and age then in your .aspx markup have 2 templatefields that have name and age.  My solution handles this for you.

Comment: Your answer was closest, but you didn't describe how to bind individual `TemplateFields` to the object's properties - you need to use `<%# Databinder.Eval(Container.DataSource, "MyPropertyName") %>`

Comment: [Darren Pope](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1243973/darren-pope) [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/212641) "@SpikeX - If you are using the BoundField object, then you do not need to use the DataBinder.Eval. You need only set the DataField attribute to the corresponding Property. Plus, I think it's cleaner. One line of code rather than 5+ (if tabbed correctly)."

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
 My Label: <asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MyTextBoxString") %>'  />
```

in the markup and similar stuff for your textbox.

```
GridView1.DataSource = MyListOfObjects
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1):

First remember any binding controls like `GridView`, `DropdownList` e.t.c bind to public properties, so first make your public members to public properties.

Then create objects of MyObject class and add them to your `List<MyObject>` object

Finally you can persist this list object by saving it in `Session` or `ViewState` to maintain it after postbacks.

I hope you can do it now!!! you can ask for more help if neccessary.