# How to bind repeater with properties of another C# Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, webusercontrol

I have a repeater inside a web user control .I need to bind it with the properties of another C# class (say abc.cs).
Can anyone please let me know how to bind the repeater with properties of another C# class?

Note:i don't have properties in webusercontrol.cs file.They have been placed and being set in another C# class.

For example

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblCloseDate" Text='<%#Eval("Property Reference") %>' runat="server" />
```

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried using the Repeater's OnDataBound or OnItemCreated event to locate the label and set the value?

Comment: This question is in vb.net, otherwise possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517676/how-do-i-bind-a-gridview-to-a-custom-object

Comment: You can't bind to an individual control, you need to put the control in a List.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to bind to _collection_ of classes? A repeater is used for ... well, repeating the same display for a collection of elements. If you only want to always display only a single instance of a class, there is no need for a repeater. Just use regular form elements.