# asp.net grid view data binding without database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner in asp.net and c#. I want to bind image and name to gridview without any database by hardcoding them in code behind.
I tried like below but these values are not binded to Gridview1. Can anyone tell me where it goes wrong?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Profile_Name" HeaderText="Profile_Name" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageUrl" HeaderText="ImageUrl" />  
</Columns>
```

```
protected GridView GridView1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.loadTable();
    }
}
private void loadTable()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt;
    DataRow dr;
    DataColumn pName;
    DataColumn pImage;

    dt = new DataTable();
    pName = new DataColumn("Profile_Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    pImage= new DataColumn("ImageURL", Type.GetType("System.String"));

    dt.Columns.Add(pName);
    dt.Columns.Add(pImage);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Profile_Name"] = "John Cena";
    dr["ImageUrl"] = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\src\\Project\\Project.Web.WebForms\\Content\\Images\\Friends-PNG-Photos.png";

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Profile_Name"] = "Hannah Ray";
    dr["ImageUrl"] = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\src\\Project\\Project.Web.WebForms\\Content\\Images\\Image.png";

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You can create a model class and use `List` or other collections (e.g. `List<ModelClassName>`) if you're not want to bind from database. Here is an example for getting started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517676/how-do-i-bind-a-gridview-to-a-custom-object.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code for help

Comment: I have edited my question with what I had followed earlier. I m not sure what goes wrong in this.

Answer (score 4):

In the background you can make a new DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Then you can add data columns and rows through the `dt.Rows` and `dt.Columns` methods, and then set:

```
DataGridView.ItemsSource = dt.defaultview;
```

Hope that you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have edited my question with what I had followed earlier. I m not sure what goes wrong in this. Can you please point out?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind all objects to a `DataGrid`:

```cs
datagrid.DataSource = object;
datagrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks @buraq enigma. I have edited my question with what I had followed earlier. I m not sure what goes wrong in this. Can you please point out?